# Is the onSaveInstanceState Bundle the same for every activity?

Tags: android, instance, savestate

Assume I have 2 Fragments which both use the onSaveInstanceState Bundle.
In both fragments I put two different strings with the same key. Do I lose one? Or is the Bundle a different instance for each activity/fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every activity/fragment has its own `Bundle`, so you won't lose any saved data in your bundle.

`Bundle` is just like any other object in android like *(String, SharedPreferences, SQLiteDatabase, AnimationUtils, etc...)*, so you can declare it in your activity/fragment normally just like any other object. It is not a special thing like many people think; thus, every activity/fragment can has its own bundle that you declare (It is usually  the default parameter declared in `onCreate()`).